# Android input date field value not clearing

Tags: javascript, android, html, datepicker

I have a input date field like this : `<input type="date" value="2013-06-10"/>`  and I am testing in Android Tablet (version 4.1.2).

A strange issue is coming while I click on the field and set another date. The old value is not getting replaced but instead the new value is getting appended to the old value (check screenshot).

This issue comes only while there is already a value set to the field. Anyone else got a similar problem?

[image: Android Date Field Issue]

Comment: did you forget the 'name' parameter ? <input type="date" value="2013-06-10" name="mydate" />

Comment: Show us how you set this field

Comment: I am setting the value from the datepicker.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the autocomplete function use this `<input type="date" value="2013-06-10" autocomplete="off" />`